# Normalize Elasticsearch score with subfield length

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents in ElasticSearch, and each document has one or many appendices. When I do a search on the text of the appendices, I often got scores greater than 1. When I do searches with really common patterns, I realize that more the document has appendices, greater its score is.
So, I aim to 'normalize' the scores, by dividing each document score by the number of appendices it has.

For example, for this query:

```
"query": {
  "match": {
    "document.appendices.text" = "What is love?"
  }
}
```

I wish to do `score = score / length(document.appendices)` but I don't know how to express it.

It that possible, or all the appendices has to be indexed as document to achieve this?

Many thanks community!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `function_score` query to alter the already calculated score `_score`

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": { "document.appendices.text": "What is love?" }
            },
            "script_score" : {
                "script" : {
                  "source": "_score/doc['document.appendices'].length"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#score-functions

Comment: Thanks for your help! It definitely seems to be the way I'm looking for. Sadly, I got a `No field found for ['appendices']  in mapping with types []` error. And I also fail to list the keys `doc` accepts, so far.

Comment: Fixed the key for `doc` to lookup length

Comment: After additional researches, it appears that elements with list type can't be accessed at all in scripts.